# Radio buttons not visible in internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am pulling my hairs just due to different issues coming in internet Explorer. I am trying to create a grid having radio buttons (Which are displayed by selecting a value in select box and a value in text box). The grid is working fine in Firefox and Google Chrome but not working in IE. Here is my java script code.

```
function contractor_details(data){

for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        var contrator_table = document.getElementById('contractor_detail');
        var cname = data[i].contractor;
        var address = data[i].address;
            }
    $('#enlistmentData').html('');
    if(data.length==1){

        $('#enlistmentData').html('<input type="hidden" name="contname" id="enlistmentinput" value= "'+data[0].contractor+'" />');

    }else{
    $('#enlistmentData').append('<table border="1" style="width:100%" id="enlistmentData_table"><tr><td></td><td><font size=3>Company Name</font></td><td><font size=3>Address</font></td></tr></table>');
$.each(data,function(k,val){
    $('#enlistmentData_table').append('<tr><td align=left><input type="radio" name="contname" value="'+val.contractor+'"></td><td>'+val.contractor+'</td><td>'+val.address+'</td></tr></table>');
        });
    }
}
```

Its only displaying the items in table i.e but the radio buttons are not visible.

Comment: ie11, or lower? Could you setup fiddle? p.s. ie is more sensitive to invalid html than other browsers, maybe answer is in generated html...

Comment: i am using Internet Explorer 8. i have not used fiddle before.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PSr9k/ -ok, place your html in top left box (named html), and update fiddle, and send link.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PSr9k/6/ check it out. I dont think so there is any mistake in HTML, i feels there is a mistake some where in java script, Bcz almost same issue was solved before. May be instead of append i have to use some thing else